# Add previous month column DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a fact table which has `'Last Data Update'` column that shows current month date(mm/dd/yyyy), 06/13/2022.

I am trying to add column called `'report month'` that returns a value that shows previous month/year 05/2022 to create relationship with calendar table.

`=Date.Month([Last Data Update])-1`

I have used this code, but this only returns `5` and it is in number format.

is there a way to return `05/2022` in DAX ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for we with this 3 simple steps:

Step 1: Create a column with current year (True/False statement) by using:

> CurrentYear = IF(YEAR([Last Data Update])=YEAR(NOW()),1,0)

Step 2: Create a column that will indicate if the current date (based on column **"Last Data Update"**) belongs to previous month or not (True/False statement).

> PreviousMonth = IF([CurrentYear]=1 && (MONTH(TODAY())-1)=MONTH([Last Data Update]),1,0)

Step 3: Create a filter on your visual where you select filter "PreviousMonth" with value "1" to show dates only from previous month).

If you like it. Don't forget to rate it.
Success,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

This is M, not DAX. Replace your custom column with the following code:

```
Text.PadStart( Text.From(Date.Month([Last Data Update])-1),2,"0") &"/"& Text.From(Date.Year([Last Data Update]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This month-year

```
FORMAT( [Last Data Update], "mm/yyyy")
```

previous month

```
FORMAT( DATEADD([Last Data Update],-1,Month), "mm/yyyy")
```